# Why did the Negotiation phase end early?

Tags: payday-3

In Payday 3, they added a negotiation phase to give you time to set some things up. You can trade hostages for more time, with a timer in the top left. However, sometimes the heist progresses to "assault incoming" with time still on the clock (and valuable hostages wasted). Why does this happen? How can I keep NYPD from beginning the assault early?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The tutorial only states that "any hostile action" will end negotiations. This can be several different things, depending on the heist, including but not limited to:

- Firing an unsilenced weapon
- Firing at First Responders with any weapon
- Killing a civilian
- Being seen exiting the building on most heists
- Starting the thermite fire on SCB

Comment: This is all fairly different between heists, for example I don't think there's any objective that causes the assault to begin early on others like on SCB but I'm not certain

Answer (score 0):

On the current patch (launch patch) occasionally the bots shoot police during the negotiations ending them prematurely.

Comment: It's hard to prove a negative here, but I'm *pretty* sure this isn't true. The bots don't seem to be interested in engaging with the first responders until the second it flips to "assault incoming". In fact, the bots stop shooting long before the guards stop shooting. Plus, the first responders also don't seem to care if a bot is outside the bank through the front door (but they do care if a player is out there).

Comment: @Unionhawk I have played quite a bit as I am sure you have and nearly every time I attempt to stealth a mission with a friend and we get caught, a bot will run out the front door and shoot the cops. The most frequent occurence of this is on "No Rest for the Wicked", but I have also encountered this on "Under the Surphaze" and "Gold and Sharke". Will attempt to get a clip so I can add it to my answer.

Comment: If you go down in stealth, and call out for help, the bots go loud. I learned that the hard way. Perhaps that is what happened?

Comment: @TimmyJim I've had them shoot cops just when one person is cuffed. Or just run out front and start shooting cops if you go too close to the door on Dirty Ice. I was planning on getting more footage but I haven't failed a stealth heist since I made this post. So I haven't captured any footage. If I have the time I will test it this weekend.